# Updating a UserCustomAction ScriptSrc

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, custom-action

I'm trying to update a `UserCustomAction` that is set on a web. I am trying to update the `ScriptSrc` url of the action to include a query string parameter, ?rev=1, but it does not seem to be taking. mainly this is to "refresh" a custom action if the underlying JavaScript file is updated. The main portion of my function looks like this:

```
Begin {
        $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
        $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName,$credential.Password)
        if($ActionType -eq "Site"){
            $site = $context.Site
        }
        else{
            $site = $context.Web
        }
        $customActions = $site.UserCustomActions
        $context.Load($customActions)         
    }
    Process {
        try{
            $customActions.GetById($Id).ScriptSrc = $ScriptSrc
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "CustomAction $Id updated" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    End {
        $context.Dispose()
    }
```

When passing in my parameters for an existing `UserCustomAction`, it says it was successful, but the query string is not set. If I create the `UserCustomAction` initially with a query string parameter, it takes. It also says that `ScriptSrc` is a settable property, so I'm not understanding why it isn't updating in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should you not do `UserCustomAction.Update()` after you set the new script source? 
(also you may want to store the action in a variable:

```
try{
    $theAction = $customActions.GetById($Id)
    $theAction.ScriptSrc = $ScriptSrc
    $theAction.Update()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "CustomAction $Id updated" -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: I'm effing stoopid sometimes. Update is what I was missing.

Comment: overworked Eric!